# Can I use the latest Bulma with the book's version 6.2

Tags: css, version, bulma

The [Bulma book](https://bleedingedgepress.com/creating-interfaces-bulma/) (Creating Interfaces with Bulma) uses version 6.2 while the current version is 7.0.

Can I use 7.0 with the book? Or will the [samples](https://github.com/troymott/bulma-book-code) break?

I.e.: are there breaking changes between the latest 7.0 and the book's version 6.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the latest changes here:

https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

v7.0 does not list any breaking changes so it should be safe to use with the v6.2 book.